# Get image src from a image in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, setattribute, getattribute

I've been looking around much today and spend a few hours trying to get something done. For a client I am creating a slideshow with a lightbox when clicked on an image. The slideshow and lightbox both work, but I don't get the right image in the lightbox yet.

This is the code that loads the slideshow and when clicked on an image opens the lightbox.
(The images for the slideshow get loaded by a php script and turned into a Javascript array)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var curimg=0;
function rotateimages(){
document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);
curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0;
}

window.onload = function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 1000);
}
</script>
<div style="width: 170px; height: 160px">
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick =          "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.    display='block'">
<img id="slideshow" src="" />
</a>
<div id="light" class="white_content">
<img id="lightImg" src="" />
<script>
var image = document.getElementById("slideshow").src;
document.getElementById("lightImg").setAttribute("src", image);
</script>
```

I now try to create a variable named "image"and let this contain the src of the current image in the slideshow. So I can load this to the image in the lightbox.

Hopefully some one can give me some usefull tips. I am pretty new in the Javascript language.

The script for the slideshow came from: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp2.shtml

Regards Koen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days there really is no excuse for using obtrusive Javascript (Stuff inside your HTML attributes, ideally it should be in an external file. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

I have done you the favour of cleaning up your code a bit, and changed it where you seemed to be going wrong. As DotNetter has already pointed out it would be sensible to use jQuery in this instance, as it really does simplify things. However, I'm going to assume that for some reason you want it in plain js. Below is a simplification of the code that you posted with the correct change.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
        width: 170px;
        height: 160px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var curimg=0;
    function rotateimages(){
        document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/" + galleryarray[curimg]);
        curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        setInterval("rotateimages()", 1000);

        document.getElementById("slideshow").onclick = function () {
            var imageSrc = document.getElementById("slideshow").src;
            document.getElementById("lightImg").setAttribute("src", imageSrc);
            document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>

<div class='wrapper'>
    <img id="slideshow" src="" />
    <div id="light" class="white_content">
        <img id="lightImg" src="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Before, you were getting the src of the current image when the page loaded, you need to be getting the src of the image when the user clicks on the

Comment: Wow, thanks, that works! I appreciate the time you guys put in helping me! :) I've got to learn much about javascript and the reason I sort of avoid jQuery at the moment is that I want to learn the core basics of JS since jQuery is just a simplificated library of Javascript as far as I know. Thanks for the help, it works!

Comment: I need a reputation of 15 to upVote hehe ^^ I'm new here, btw, do you think my argument to learn Javascript is good? Or would you advice me to go for jQuery?

Comment: I'd forgotten that! I would say look at jQuery whenever you want. I learned it fairly early on and it helped me to understand some parts of Javascript. Remember they are not mutually exclusive, you can try some jQuery and if it works for you then keep going! If not head back to JS for a while and pick up a few more of the basics.

Comment: I agree with that and in most cases jQuery would probably suffice. But in a few years I would like to look on this site and give feedback to others that have a question! I'm only 19 years at this time so theres much to learn ahead! Thanks.